# Ace editor dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, css, ace-editor

In my html `pug` definition I have following `div`s:

```
div(id='wrapper')
        div(id='editor' class='editor')
```

where 2nd one contains ace editor. If `wrapper` (container) div has fixed `height` ace editor displays fine:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 640px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
}

div.editor {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
}
```

But if I want to make `#wrapper` with dynamic height as well:

```
    height: 90%;
```

ace editor collapses into 1px height. What is the problem here, how to solve?

Comment: @Ahmad, it is not an `html` - it is `pug` as I mentioned :)

Comment: Use vh instead of percent, see demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/m3tc0naL/

Comment: I mistook it for a typo of `bug` :) my bad

Comment: @PatrickHund, yes this works, thanks!!! Put this as an answer.

Comment: I was going to, but the question has already been closed as duplicate ¯\_(ツ)_/¯